# How to replace properties which are defined in .componentType file using deployment config plan?

Tags: bpel, sca, oracle-soa

Is there a way to replace preferences which are configured in BPEL componentType file during deployment config plan? Let's say
(If I move these properties in `<component>` in composite.xml, config plan works fine. I am looking solution for componentType preferences)

My .componentType file as follows

```
<componentType ..............>
    <property name="preference.somePreference" type="xs:string">actualValue</property> 
</componentType>
```

and my deployment_config_plan.xml as follows

```
<component name="orderProcessor">
<property name="preference.somePreference"><replace>someValue</replace> 
</property> 
</component>
```

Comment: This is less a BPEL question and more related to SCA. It would be helpful to know which tool you use.

Comment: @vanto, I am using Oracle SOA Suite 11g and JDeveloper is my IDE and for BPEL components I am using BPEL version 2.0.

Comment: @vanto, Am I missing anything... (hmmm I don't think so)...

Comment: no I guess there is simply no one who can help at the moment. It's pretty specific question.

Answer (score 1):

There are no way to replacing such a thing on config plan. You need to move your preferences inside de tag

The same thing happens when you have references on a .componentType file. You need to wrapp this references in a Wrapper.wsdl file. Afterwards you  can change references of this Wrapper.wsdl on cfgplan.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Sample file **MQin_mq.jca**:

```
<adapter-config name="MQ_QUEUEin" adapter="MQSeriesAdapter" wsdlLocation="MQ_QUEUEin.wsdl" xmlns="http://platform.integration.oracle/blocks/adapter/fw/metadata">

  <connection-factory location="eis/MQ/APP" adapterRef=""/>
  <endpoint-activation portType="Dequeue_ptt" operation="Dequeue" UITransmissionPrimitive="Dequeue">
    <activation-spec className="oracle.tip.adapter.mq.inbound.ActivationSpecImpl">
      <property name="QueueName" value="__MQ_QUEUE__"/>
      <property name="InboundThreadCount" value="1"/>
      <property name="UseMessageEncodingForTranslation" value="false"/>
    </activation-spec>
  </endpoint-activation>
</adapter-config>
```

ANT build.xml script file will replace properties placeholder to value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project default="deploy" basedir=".">
    <target name="deploy">      
        <delete dir="temp" />
        <delete dir="temp2" />
        <unzip src="${basedir}/sca_app_rev${deploy.revision}.jar"
               dest="temp" />
        <replaceregexp file="temp/MQin_mq.jca"
                       match="__MQ_QUEUE__"
                       replace="${app.queue.MQ_QUEUE}" />
        <mkdir dir="temp2" />
        <zip destfile="${basedir}/temp2/sca_app_rev${deploy.revision}.jar"
             basedir="temp" />      
        <ant antfile="ant-sca-deploy.xml" dir="${env.BEA_HOME}/jdeveloper/bin">
                <property name="serverURL" value=" http://${weblogic.host}:8001" />
                <property name="sarLocation" value="${basedir}@{dir}/sca_app_rev${deploy.revision}.jar" />
                <property name="overwrite" value="true" />
                <property name="user" value="weblogic" />
                <property name="password" value="${weblogic.password}" />
                <property name="forceDefault" value="true" />
                <property name="failOnError" value="true" />
            </ant>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Mind adding some text to explain your answer?